# How to differentiate Browser vs Portable(Standalone) browser through asp objects or C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string strBrowserDetail = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
Response.Write(strBrowserDetail);
```

I only have this way to get the Browser details. But this is not find Browser is standalone or not. Is it possible to distinguish both ? If it is, you to achieve this ?